# Custom Property doesn't show in Properties window of the Custom control

Tags: c#, winforms

I said File->New->Control Library

Dropped a ListView on its form, ADDED a new static class to it like this:

```
namespace WindowsFormsControlLibrary1
{
    public  static class TestClass
    {
        [Category("Appearance")]
        public static Color InsertionMarkColor { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But I am expecting to a see a property called InsertionMarkColor when I use this in a test application but it doesn't show there. Why?
Note: If I directly copy-paste that InsertionMarkColor in the source code of the Library, it shows and works but if I want to move it like the code above to a separate class, it doesn't work...What do you think is missing?

Comment: removed the word "static", still not showing. :(

Comment: What do you mean by separate class?  The property has to be a part of the control.  Did you inherit from the ListView control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
public class MyListView : ListView {

  [Category("Appearance")]
  public Color InsertionMarkColor { get; set; }

}
```